# Link Popup Modal to correct script in loop

Tags: templating, javascript

Popup Closed Screenshot
[image]

---

Popup Open Screenshot
[image]

I have image that has multiple markers on it that can be clicked to bring up different popups. However, I need to some help refining the code to work properly and to link to the correct id tag.

My template code:

```
{% set var = craft.entries.section('availablehomes').relatedTo(category).level(2) %}
{% for entry in var %}
<!-- Popup Modal -->
{% set plotPopup = 'plotPopup' ~ entry.title|camel %}
<div class="property popup" id="{{ plotPopup }}">
....markup.......
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Which outputs

```
<div class="property popup" id="plotPopupplot1">...</div>
<div class="property popup" id="plotPopupplot2">...</div>
<div class="property popup" id="plotPopupplot3">...</div>
<div class="property popup" id="plotPopupplot4">...</div>
```

And below is the current script text:

```
<script>
// When the user clicks on plot number, open the popup
function openPopup() {
{% set plottitle = craft.entries.section('availablehomes').relatedTo(category).level(2) %}
{% for entry in plottitle %}
    var popup = document.getElementById('plotPopup{{ entry.title|json_encode()|camel }}');
{% endfor %}
    popup.classList.toggle('show');
}
</script>
```

Which is printing out as:

```
<script>
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
function openPopup() {
    var popup = document.getElementById('plotPopupplot1');
    var popup = document.getElementById('plotPopupplot2');
    var popup = document.getElementById('plotPopupplot3');
    var popup = document.getElementById('plotPopupplot4');
    popup.classList.toggle('show');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a JavaScript problem. You have to add an event listener to the marker which opens the corresponding popup.

I put together a little example on JSBin here: https://jsbin.com/tigefikalu/edit?html,js,console,output

Hope that helps with the logic.

Comment: Thankyou it's almost there. As it's selecting the different popups correctly. However, when I click to activate it, it scrolls me back to the top of the page. Which I'm assuming is something to do with the #?

Comment: I've got it to stop jumping back to the top by adding `return false;` at the end of the script. Thanks for your help.